# Does istio ServiceEntry support routing to different hosts by requesting pod lables?

Tags: routes, istio

Let's say I have a service, which has 2 pods, podA and podB, both of them need to access an external resource, which is defined as istio ServiceEntry with two hosts, externalResourceA and externalResourceB. However, I wish podA will always access externalResourceA and podB will always access externalResourceB.

Is this *routing by requester* possible with serviceEntry/WorkloadSelector?

https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/sidecar/#WorkloadSelector
The documentation seems to shed a light on this, but I didn't succeed in finding out the right recipe to cook it out.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve and what is the goal? Are your `podA` and `podB` replicas (like externalResourceA and externalResourceB)? Is everything in one cluster?

Comment: yes, podA and podB are replicas of a same service, and externalResoureA and externalResourceB can be two different services (of a same kind, e.g. database, redis and etc)

Comment: However, if everything is in one cluster, in my opinion there is no point in creating routing with ServiceEntry. Why do you need to use serviceEntry in your solution? Additionally, serviceEntry does not support labels at all.

Comment: externalResources are out of the cluster.

Comment: ServiceEntry doesn't support labels. Did you think about [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)? It could be solution to your problem.